# Group by and PIVOT in same T-SQL

Tags: t-sql

I'm trying to group the job history per job and week and get the max, avg and min duration of the job and also how many failed, succeeded, retry and canceled has occurred on that job that week and then make everything in to a html table and mail it.

But the problem is I don't know how do the PIVOT to get the sum of each status on each job per week. 
What do i need to make this work?

```
DECLARE @body NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @subjectstring NVARCHAR(256)

SET     @body =  N'<H4>SQL Job history on ' + @@servername + '</H4>' +
    + N'<table border="1">'
    + N'<tr><th>week</th><th>name</th><th>max</th><th>avg</th><th>min</th><th>Failed</th><th>Succeeded</th><th>Retry</th><th>Canceled</th></tr>'
    + CAST((
SELECT  [master].[dbo].[cfn_F_ISO_WEEK_OF_YEAR](CONVERT(varchar(10), convert(datetime, CAST([run_date] AS NVARCHAR(8)), 112), 23)) AS [td]
        ,j.name AS td
               ,MAX(h.run_duration) AS [td]
               ,AVG(h.run_duration) AS [td]
               ,MIN(h.run_duration) AS [td]
               ,[0] AS [td]
               ,[1] AS [td]
               ,[2] AS [td]
               ,[3] AS [td]
FROM   (msdb.dbo.sysjobs j 
       INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory h 
               ON h.job_id = j.job_id)
    PIVOT(SUM(h.run_status) FOR [MYGROUPBY] IN ([0], [1], [2],[3]))
WHERE j.name IN ( 'IndexOptimize - ALL_DATABASES', 'BizTalkProdIndexMaintenance.Subplan_1', 'Backup BizTalk Server (BizTalkMgmtDb)', 'SSIS Server Maintenance Job')  AND 
    step_id = 0 
    AND [master].[dbo].[cfn_F_ISO_WEEK_OF_YEAR](CONVERT(varchar(10), convert(datetime, CAST([run_date] AS NVARCHAR(8)), 112), 23)) > [master].[dbo].[cfn_F_ISO_WEEK_OF_YEAR](GETDATE())-2
    GROUP BY 
        [master].[dbo].[cfn_F_ISO_WEEK_OF_YEAR](CONVERT(varchar(10), convert(datetime, CAST([run_date] AS NVARCHAR(8)), 112), 23))
        ,j.name 
ORDER  BY [master].[dbo].[cfn_F_ISO_WEEK_OF_YEAR](CONVERT(varchar(10), convert(datetime, CAST([run_date] AS NVARCHAR(8)), 112), 23)) ASC
        FOR XML RAW('tr'), ELEMENTS
    ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
    + N'</table>'          


SET @subjectstring = 'x - Job history ' + CAST(@@servername as nvarchar(64))

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @recipients='mymail', @subject = @subjectstring, @body = @body, @body_format = 'HTML', @profile_name = 'mail.customer.se'
GO
```

I want a result like this

```
name, week, maxduration, avgduration, minduration, 0, 1, 2, 3
--------------------------------------
job1, 46, 70, 56, 45, 7, 1, 0, 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took a while but i found a solution to my problem:

```
DECLARE @body NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @subjectstring NVARCHAR(256)

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MyResultTable', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #MyResultTable

; 
WITH mytable 
     AS (SELECT [master].[dbo].[Cfn_f_iso_week_of_year]( 
                           msdb.dbo.Agent_datetime(h.run_date, h.run_time)) AS 
                [Week] 
                , 
                msdb.dbo.Agent_datetime(h.run_date, h.run_time) 
                AS RunTime, 
                j.NAME, 
                master.dbo.cfn_agent_time(h.run_duration) as run_duration, 
                h.run_status, 
                h.instance_id 
         FROM   msdb.dbo.sysjobs j 
                INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory h 
                        ON h.job_id = j.job_id 
         WHERE  h.step_id = 0 
         ), 
     resulttable 
     AS (SELECT pt.[week], 
                pt.[name], 
                pt.run_duration, 
                [0] AS Failed, 
                [1] AS Succeeded, 
                [2] AS Retry, 
                [3] AS Canceled 
         FROM   mytable 
                PIVOT(Count(mytable.instance_id) 
                     FOR mytable.run_status IN ([0], 
                                                [1], 
                                                [2], 
                                                [3])) AS pt) 
SELECT RT.[week], 
       RT.[name], 
       Sum(RT.failed)         AS Failed, 
       Sum(RT.succeeded)      AS Succeeded, 
       Sum(RT.retry)          AS Retry, 
       Sum(RT.canceled)       AS Canceled, 
       MAX(RT.[run_duration]) AS [Max], 
       AVG(RT.[run_duration]) AS [Avg], 
       MIN(RT.[run_duration]) AS [Min] 
       INTO #MyResultTable
FROM   resulttable AS RT 
WHERE RT.[Week] > [master].[dbo].[Cfn_f_iso_week_of_year](GETDATE())-2
GROUP  BY RT.[week], 
          RT.[name] 
ORDER  BY [week]



SET     @body =  N'<H4>SQL Job history on ' + @@servername + ' - Version 2</H4>' +
    + N'<table border="1">'
    + N'<tr><th>week</th><th>name</th><th>Failed</th><th>Succeeded</th><th>Retry</th><th>Canceled</th><th>Max</th><th>Avg</th><th>Min</th></tr>'
    + CAST((
    SELECT 
         t.Week AS [td]
         ,t.name AS [td]
         ,t.Failed AS [td]
         ,t.Succeeded AS [td]
         ,t.Retry AS [td]
         ,t.Canceled AS [td]
         ,REPLACE(CAST(t.Max AS DECIMAL)/86400, '.', ',') AS [td]
         ,REPLACE(CAST(t.Avg AS DECIMAL)/86400, '.', ',') AS [td]
         ,REPLACE(CAST(t.Min AS DECIMAL)/86400, '.', ',') AS [td]
    FROM #MyResultTable t
    ORDER BY t.[week]
        FOR XML RAW('tr'), ELEMENTS
    ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
    + N'</table>'          

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MyResultTable', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #MyResultTable


SET @subjectstring = 'CustomerName - Job history ' + CAST(@@servername as nvarchar(64))

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @recipients='email1@customer.com;email2@customer.com', @subject = @subjectstring, @body = @body, @body_format = 'HTML', @profile_name = 'mail.customer.se'
GO
```